# Compare if one string is greater than another in kdb

Tags: kdb

I want to check which of the two strings in greater, for which I have was using below logic but it fails in few cases

```
q){$[1b in x>=y;x;y]}["b";"b"]
"b"
q){$[1b in x>=y;x;y]}["c";"b"]
"c"
q){$[1b in x>=y;x;y]}["azz";"dff"] // Wrong output (Reason for failure - "azz">"dff" --> 011b)
"azz" / desired output dff
```

Please suggest another way to get the greatest string of the provided strings?

Since comparison operator compares character by character hence in "azz" and "dff" if the output can be displayed as "dff" only after comparison for "d" from "dff" and "a" from "azz" as "a" is less than "d".

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by greatest string, and can you explicitly state what you want your output to be?

Comment: updated with example.

Comment: Please, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598596/kdb-string-comparison-with-a-table/53603520#53603520)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to symbol and use <, >, etc.. These operators perform lexicographic comparisons for symbols.
https://code.kx.com//q4m3/4_Operators/

```
q) `azz < `dff
1b
```

If you insist on strings then you can leverage [iasc](https://code.kx.com//q4m3/A_Built-in_Functions/#a37-iasc) to creat a "smaller-or-equal"-like function:

```
q) not first iasc ("azz"; "dff")
1b
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `1b in` is equivalent to any in this case as `"azz">"dff"` equates to `011b`. Your conditional will evaluate true as 2 letters in "azz" are greater than "dff".

It is better to cast x and y to symbols and compare as this will evaluate with 1 boolean:

`` (`$"azz")>=`$"dff"
0b ``

`` {$[(`$x)>=`$y;x;y]}["azz";"dff"]
"dff" ``

Alternatively you could sort desc order and take the first result:

`{first desc(x;y)}["azz";"dff"]
"dff"`